# Setting line-height and allowing break-word

Tags: html, css, html-table

I should have a very easy question here. I have a table and want to set the line-height of each cell to 8%. I also have break-word enabled. If the width of the page is decreased, the text gets overlapped (because I explicitly set the line height). See code implementation:

```
table, th, td {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 450;
  word-break: break-word;
  line-height: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}
```

example:

[image]

As you can see, the text is overlapping. Although I want to explicitly assign the line-height, I also want the cells to grow if the text is moved to two lines. As you can see in the css file, I tried using margin-bottom but no luck. Any suggestions is appreciated. thanks in advance!

this solved my issue:

```
 tr, th, td {
   font-weight: 450;
   font-size: 11px;
   word-break: break-word;
   line-height: 90%;
 }
```

Comment: can you try instead line-height only `height: 8%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-height: 8%;` means 8% of the *font size*  of that element, which is what causes the described overlapping.

Try a value like "110%" or "1.1" (which equals 110%), and try to adjust that value as needed in the browser tools until you find a value that fits your expectations.

Also, I would apply that only to the `td`, and the `margin` only to the `table`. If you need space inside the cells, use `padding` on those.

Comment: Thank you! This helped! I think separating the td/table solved my issue.